# How to get data from a flask-mqtt callback into a continuous flask text/event-stream response?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to adapt [this](https://ron.sh/creating-real-time-charts-with-flask/) guide for real-time charts in Flask so that data received via MQTT in the backend can be passed to the frontend via Server Sent Events. For receiving MQTT data I use flask-mqtt. I can receive data from a topic with the following callback function:

```
@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_messages(client, userdata, message):
    print('Received message on topic {}: {}'
          .format(message.topic, message.payload.decode()))
```

The guide describes that data from Flask can be retrieved from the frontend using the following function:

```
@application.route('/chart-data')
def chart_data():
    def generate_random_data():
        while True:
            json_data = json.dumps(
                {'time': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'value': random.random() * 100})
            yield f"data:{json_data}\n\n"
            time.sleep(1)

    return Response(generate_random_data(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

The question now is how can I transfer the data from my MQTT callback function `handle_messages()` into the `chart_data()` method so that MQTT data is transferred from the backend to the frontend via SSE?

I would like to implement the solution mostly in Flask without having to install additional servers like with Socket.io or REDIS. I also prefer not to connect to the MQTT broker in the frontend via websockets.

Comment: what `Flask` / `Python` version? and why you don't want to use `flask_socketio`?

Comment: I´m using `Python==3.9` and `Flask==2.0.1`. I don´t need a bidirectional connection to receive and send data from the backend, I just need to receive data in the Frontend, thats why i wanted to avoid sockets. If the `flask-socketio` solution will be easier to implement than my SSE approach, I´m also open using `flask-socketio`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `flask_socketio`:

```
# app.py
import eventlet
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

eventlet.monkey_patch()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET'] = 'my secret key'
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'broker.hivemq.com'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = ''
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 5
app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False


mqtt = Mqtt(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('publish')
def handle_publish(data):
    mqtt.publish('top1', data['message'])


@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode()
    )
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mqtt.subscribe('top1')
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False, debug=True)
```

*templates/index.html*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charSet="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('mqtt_message', (data) => {
            const text = '(' + data['topic'] + ' qos: ' + data['qos'] + ') ' + data['payload'];
            // update chart here...
            $('#subscribe_messages').append(text + '<br/><br/>');
        })
    });
</script>
<div id="subscribe_messages"></div>
```

run server, open a few tabs and open browser console:

```
// connect and send 2 messages into top1
const s = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
s.emit("publish", {"message": "hello1"});
s.emit("publish", {"message": "hello2"});
// you will see the messages into all tabs
```

About `SSE` without `flask_socketio`. You can try to use `Queue` for messages(**is just an example**):

```
# app.py
import datetime
import json
import time
from queue import Queue

import eventlet
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt

eventlet.monkey_patch()
QUEUE = Queue()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET'] = 'my secret key'
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'broker.hivemq.com'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = ''
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 5
app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False

mqtt = Mqtt(app)
mqtt.subscribe('top1')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode()
    )
    QUEUE.put(data)


@app.route('/publish')
def publish():
    mqtt.publish('top1', json.dumps({'dt': str(datetime.datetime.now())}).encode())
    return 'ok'


@app.route('/chart-data')
def chart_data():
    def events():
        while True:
            message = QUEUE.get()
            if message is None:
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

            yield "data: %s\n\n" % str(message)
    return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

*templates/index.html*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      const source = new EventSource('/chart-data');
      source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          // update chart here...
          $('#subscribe_messages').append(e.data + '<br/><br/>');
        }, false);
  });
</script>
<div id="subscribe_messages"></div>
```

Open `/`, open a few times in a new tab `/chart-data` and check `/` route. You'll see event-messages.

Also you can look at [Quart](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart), [flask[async]](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/), [aio-pika](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [aioamqp](https://github.com/Polyconseil/aioamqp).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and understandable explanation, that helped me a lot. A small detail question about scaling across multiple topics and charts per view: Does it make more sense to open a separate websocket for each sub-topic or is one object sufficient for multiple topics that is then split in the JS logic?

Comment: @JohnDizzle hmmm . nice question. it's depends only on how much events per second and how much charts. also we have a DOM manipulation... difficult to answer. I think your question can only be answered with the help of performance tests. Anyway you can implement 'alpha' version and check performance with 1 websocket. Also you can increase amount of charts + events. not sure if I can give any advice on this (((

Comment: @JohnDizzle JFYI: Most often, cryptocurrency API contain many subscribers and events. Looks like [coinbase API](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#subscribe) uses bidirectional protocol and 1 socket per multiple currencies(charts). see: `product_ids` section.